# Webform Component with multiple fields

Tags: 7, forms, webforms

I would like to make a custom module that integrates with webform (7.4).

I need to have a combo field which could be added to a form as one field but consists of 4 text areas.

I have found a discussion on this topic here -> http://drupal.org/node/965068 but first its confusing how he does it at the end he just says he figured it out, but also this is a solution for 6.3 and i need for the 7.4

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In the referenced URL they specifically do not want something 'out of the box' or 'built into the webform UI'.  Is this a requirement here as well, or will already available features valid answers?

Comment: While it's slightly off-topic, did you consider using regular Drupal content type creation mechanism or ECK instead of Webforms? This way you gain access to a multitude field related modules, and something like field collection would probably solve your problem out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

You could use https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_addmore.

A more flexible solution would be to use the Entityform module in combination with https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection.